# What does this Hadith mean?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

I can't understand the following Hadith:

> قوله صلى الله عليه وسلم:  ليس الشديد بالصرعة, إنما الشديد الذي يملك نفسه عند الغضب
>
> The strong is not the one who overcomes the people by his strength, but the strong is the one who controls himself while in anger.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/141) & [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/45/140)</sup>

This Hadith was in Al-Saadi's tafsir of Al-Baqara 2:177

May Allah give us a better understanding of the religion, jazakum Allah khayran

Comment: Your question needs elaboration. What exactly do you not understand about it? This hadith is also from Bukhari and Muslim, so linking directly to them would be more useful as would posting a translation.

Comment: You should point at what sounds unclear to you because this hadith is rather self explanatory.

Comment: Ah sorry, at first I thought shadeed (شديد) meant extreme

Comment: Ok in shaa Allah it will benefit someone. Jazakum Allah khayran

Answer (score 1):

In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful.

In the Hadith, the beloved Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) points out that strength isn't attributed to a person who uses his muscles to overcome others, rather strength is attributed to someone who can control his anger. Undoubtedly, this is right conduct. As the All Knowing said:

[image]

> And indeed, you are of a great moral character.
>
> *[Al-Qalam 68:4]*